# Why is my Meteor template context data not being saved?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm scratching my head at this because I remember this exact code working at some point in the past. When `test` is created and rendered I set the value of `this.data` but I can't retrieve it in events or helpers. I'm beginning to think that a package or something screwed up my Meteor.

```
<template name="test">
  <button>click me</button>    
</template>
```

```
Template.test.onCreated(function(){
  // here I am setting the data context of the test template
  this.data = {
    doors: 5
  };

  // when I hover over `this` in Chrome is indeed shows the object
  debugger
});

Template.test.onRendered(function(){

  this.data = {
    wheels: 4
  };
  // when I hover over `this` it also shows the object
  debugger

  var changeDataContext = function(obj){
    this.data = obj;
  };

  changeDataContext( {engine: 1} );

  // when I hover over `this` it shows the old value of `this`, not the new one with {engine: 1}
  this;
  debugger
});


Template.test.events({

  'click button': function(e, tmpl){
    tmpl;

    // when I hover over `tmpl` it shows null for `data`???
    debugger
  }

});

Template.test.helpers({

  images: function () {
    this;

    // when I hover over `this` it shows null for the value of `this`???
    debugger
    return this.wheels;
  }

});
```

**EDIT**

Here is a MeteorPad outlining the problem:

http://meteorpad.com/pad/Cqw3fWieJfspK2eYv/Leaderboard

Check out the debugger statements here:

http://app-5p5urzku.meteorpad.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with your scopes. First, for `onRendered`, you cannot use `this` inside a function and expect it to be considered like `this` from a higher scope:

```
Template.test.onRendered(function(){

  this.data = {
    wheels: 4
  };

  var self = this; // we save this scope's `this` for later

  var changeDataContext = function(obj){
    this.data = obj; // here, `this` refers to the current scope, ergo your changeDataContext function! onRendered's `this` does not get altered.
    self.data = obj; // here, we refer to the `self` variable that you set earlier. It should work.
  };

  changeDataContext( {engine: 1} );

  // tadaaaaaaaaaa
  this;
  debugger
});
```

Then, for helpers: `this` represents the **data context**, not the **template instance**. If you want the template instance, use `Template.instance()`:

```
Template.test.helpers({

  images: function () {
    var tmpl = Template.instance();
    if (tmpl.data)
       return tmpl.data.wheels;
  }

});
```

**Please note:** the data context is *different* from `Template.instance().data`. You cannot put stuff into `this.data` in `onCreated` and expect to be able to use it in your Spacebars template. Iron router just stores it there as well for convenience.

As for your event... Well there, it should work. What you wrote should show you `wheels`. Maybe you are altering your instance's `data` in a way beforehand? To be sure, you can use `Template.instance()` instead of `tmpl`

Comment: Hmmm.. I guess I'm confused between `data context` and just, well, data. I want to stash some data inside the template instance. Isn't the `data context` the values inside the `data` key that a template instance has?

Comment: Nope! As I said in my "Please note", they are different. The data context is usually set using helpers, your router, or a parent template's inclusion. `Template.instance().data` is only a convenient property that iron router (and others, I assume) uses to store what it has put in the data context for easy access on your template's javascript code. Setting something in your template instance's `data` does not add it to its data context.

Comment: To clarify, the "data context" is essentially set by whoever calls the template, not by the template itself. The "arguments" to the template, if you want. If you want to store things inside the template instance, put them inside `this.whatever` inside `onRendered`/`onCreated`/etc and you can access them using `Template.instance().whatever` in helpers or using the second argument `tmpl.whatever` in event handlers.

Comment: @BraveKenny and @user3374348, I've added a MeteorPad to my OP. Please check it out because things are still returning `null`